# How to calculate permutations with repetitions in python

Tags: python

How to find number of permutations when items are repeated?
For example, for the string `aab` I want the following output: `aab`, `aba`, `baa`.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement,  I think

Comment: Do you want a list of those permutations, a generator of those permutations, a printout of those permutations, or just a calculation of the number of permutations? Your first sentence and your second contradict each other on this point. Also, will the input string be short or long--does efficiency matter or do you prefer simplicity? Finally, if you want a list, generator, or printout, does the order of the permutations matter and does each permutation need to be a string--does the result need to match your example output exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the standard-library [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) module:

```
from itertools import permutations


iterable = "aab"
print(set(permutations(iterable, len(iterable))))
```

By executing that code, I get the following output:

```
None@vacuum:~$ python3.6 ./test.py 
{('b', 'a', 'a'), ('a', 'b', 'a'), ('a', 'a', 'b')}
```

Answer (score 2):

> ### [`more-itertools.distinct_permutations(iterable)`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.distinct_permutations)
>
> Yields successive distinct permutations of the elements in *iterable*.
>
> Equivalent to `set(permutations(iterable))`, except duplicates are not
>   generated and thrown away. For larger input sequences, **this is much
>   more efficient**.

```
from more_itertools import distinct_permutations

for p in distinct_permutations('aab'):
    print(''.join(p))

# baa
# aba
# aab
```

Installation:

```
pip install more-itertools
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
import itertools
set(itertools.permutations('aab'))
```

The [`permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) will produce all permutations, but it will repeat some of it's output because it can't differentiate between `a1 a2 b`  and `a2 a1 b`. Here `a1` is the first occurrence of `a`, and `a2` the second. So you need to just keep the unique elements, and a `set` is a good way to do that, as the constructor transforms the input iterable into a unique collection.